# Why are my observations disappearing when using map_df()?

Tags: r, mapping

[Apologies for the edit. Midnight posting makes for poor quality questions.]

I'm trying to map char strings into columns using map_df(). The columns are created, but with no observations.

```
a <- "Master Dev: ABC"
b <- "Developer: 123"
c <- "Contractor: XYZ"
d <- "Financer: 789"

list <- list(a,b,c,d)

list %>% 
  map_df(~list(Master     = .x %>% str_subset(.,"Master Dev: ") %>% sub(".*Master Dev: ","",.),
               Architect  = .x %>% str_subset(.,"Architect: ")  %>% sub(".*Architect: ","",.),
               Contractor = .x %>% str_subset(.,"Contractor: ") %>% sub(".*Contractor: ","",.),
               Financer   = .x %>% str_subset(.,"Financer: ")   %>% sub(".*Financer: ","",.)
              )
         ) ->dF
```

The code is set within a loop, so each iteration may contain any combination of the titles in a,b,c,d. The expected output is a data frame of the information after the colon separated into respective columns.

| Master Dev | Developer | Contractor | Financer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC |  |  |  |
|  | 123 |  |  |
|  |  | xyz |  |
|  |  |  | 789 |

I know str_subset() and sub() are working fine because the following test gives me the respective company names, correctly parsed from the string.

```
list %>%
  str_subset(.,"Master Dev: ") %>% sub(".*Master Dev: ","",.)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: @MauritsEvers see question edit. Thank you.